# change a tag class name in all files

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code

i want to change a tag class name in vscode in a simple way
so how should i do this when i want this name change in all html,css and js file and i dont have to change one by one

Comment: Under the Edit menu - "find in files", and "replace in files".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your open your whole project directory with VS Code, then press `CTRL + SHIFT + F` this will bring up the multifile search menu where you can search the contents of many files at the same time.

Type the search term that will help you find the tag.

Then click on the chevron arrow on the left of the search bar to get an replace options. Here there will be an input to enter what you want to replace your tag with. After entering everything required press the little AB button on the right of the replace input and all changes should be made.